# Swipe to change activity in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've wanted to implement something similar to the `ViewPager 2`, but in compose. Firstly, I've read somewhere that I should rather not use fragments, just activities. Secondly, I was about to make some kind of an adapter, but I didn't find much resources about connecting all of these. Also, I've read that the compose pager is not meant to hold activities, so there's my question - what should I use then? What could provide similar experience? I'd like to have a couple of activities, that could be changed to left/right swipe.

Comment: "Firstly, I've read somewhere that I should rather not use fragments, just activities" -- for what you are seeking, that is better phrased as "not use fragments, just composables". A Compose UI app has few activities, sometimes only one. Activities are not used for individual screens in a Compose UI app, let alone for pages in a pager. You could use `HorizontalPager()` as your `ViewPager2` replacement, with composables as pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jetpack Compose is designed to work with a single Activity. Within that Activity, you show different Composables.

Have a look at the [`HorizontalPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/package-summary#HorizontalPager(androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PagerState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,androidx.compose.foundation.pager.PageSize,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TargetedFlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.snapping.SnapPosition,kotlin.Function2)) Composable. It provides similar functionality to the `ViewPager2`. You will not need an adapter in Jetpack Compose.

```
val state = rememberPagerState { 10 }  // define number of pages within PagerState
HorizontalPager(
    state = state,  // assign PagerState
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) { page ->  // page is an Int that holds the index of the current page
    
    // put the Composable that you want to displayed depending on the page
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = page.toString(), fontSize = 32.sp)
    }
}
```

If you want to show completely different Composables as the pages, you can use a `switch` or `if` statement in the `HorizontalPager` body like this:

```
when (page) {
    0 -> MyComposable1()
    1 -> MyComposable2()
    2 -> MyComposable3()
    else -> { 
        DefaultComposable()
    }
}
```